# How to do a larger number operations

Tags: java, long-integer

I need to calculate much larger numbers than a long integer can store (example 1234567890*1234).
Is there any way to surpass that memory capacity?

Comment: How about `BigInteger`?

Comment: You can use BigInteger: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: And by the way it does not exceed the range of `long` so you can use primitive for faster calculation

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash indeed it does thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String).  Here is an example.

```
BigInteger v = BigInteger.valueOf(1234567890);
BigInteger prod = v.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(1234));
System.out.println(prod);
```

If the numbers don't fit into a long, the supply them with a String.

```
v = new BigInteger("4994949234567890");
prod = v.multiply(new BigInteger("1234920292029292292"));
System.out.println(prod);
```

Prints

```
1523456776260
6168364167424068724128019127703880
```

The floating point counterpart is [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use with :

```
BigInteger num= new BigInteger("1234567890*1234");
```

Comment: `BigInteger` won't take an arithmatic expression for its constructor, you would need to `new BigInteger("1234567890").multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(1234))`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick with pure Java you can use BigInteger, but you could use the [jscience](http://jscience.org/). It's a great library with tons of optimizations for those kinds of problems.

Maybe this class, [LargeInteger](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/LargeInteger.html), will be good for you.

[Here](http://jscience.org/api/overview-summary.html#TUTORIAL) is an example for you:

```
LargeInteger dividend = LargeInteger.valueOf("3133861182986538201");
LargeInteger divisor = LargeInteger.valueOf("25147325102501733369");
Rational rational = Rational.valueOf(dividend, divisor);
System.out.println("rational  = " + rational);

> rational  = 41/329
```